# "Function Expected" error in JsProvider.ashx after setting a lookup field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I have an HTML page that gets opened when clicking a ribbon button of a custom entity page. The JS code running in this page is does some business logic, and eventually needs to update a lookup field back on the custom entity page.

Currently, for setting the lookup value, I'm doing something like the following*:

```
window.opener.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ik_reportid").setValue([{
    id: "d67aa9d8-c528-e711-80f2-005056b74923",
    name: "test record",
    entityType: "ik_report"
}]);
```

*Note: The above is written hard-coded for simplifying this question. I assure you the problem is not in these values, but somewhere else.

After doing so, the HTML page continues with its existing code, and eventually calls `window.opener.Page.data.refresh(true)`, and then closes itself with `window.close()`.

The problem is that when the opener page is refreshing, I get an error "function expected", and opening the debugger get me to the following line in `JsProvider.ashx`:

```
Mscrm.FormInputControl.LookupUIBehavior.$2I=function($p0,$p1){if(!parseInt($p0.type)&&!parseInt($p1.type)||parseInt($p0.category)===LookupItemCategories.UNKNOWN_EMAIL&&parseInt($p1.category)===LookupItemCategories.UNKNOWN_EMAIL)
```

I watched the values of `p0` and `p1`, and I noticed they don't have a `category` property. However, when I tried using the same code for setting the value of the same lookup field when I'm on the page itself (i.e., omitting the `window.opener', and even calling a`refresh`), I get no error.

In addition, I commented-out the `refresh` call inside the HTML page code. That didn't help, too: when I clicked the save button on the entity page, I again got the "function expected" error, now in `Global.ashx` (`b` was expected to be a function, apparently) :

```
Sys._isInstanceOfType=function(c,b){if(typeof b==="undefined"||b===null)return false; if(b instanceof c) return true;
```

No idea what's the cause for it. Any help is welcomed.

Comment: **0** Can you confirm that the error does not occur if the dialog does not open? **1** Does the error occur if you comment out all of the bus logic in the dialog? **2** Does it occur if you click Save while the dialog is still open? **2** How are you opening the dialog? **3** Instead of triggering setValue and refresh from the dialog via window.opener, try adding functions to your ribbon JS that does those things on behalf of the dialog. So your dialog would call `window.opener.setReportId([{/*snip*/}])` and then `window.opener.refreshForm()`.

Comment: 0 - yes, 1 -"bus logic"? 2a - yes, 2b - with `window.open` 3 - I'll try it

Comment: @Polshgiant, it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting messages between windows should meet your requirements here. You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
Basically in your parent window do something like this:

```
window.onmessage = function (e) {
     //e.data will contain some payload
    Xrm.Page.getAttributes("xxx").setValue(e.data);
};
```

Or to be compatible with all browsers:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    //e.data will contain some payload
    Xrm.Page.getAttributes("xxx").setValue(e.data);
  });
}
else { // IE8 or earlier
  window.attachEvent('onmessage', function (e) {
     //e.data will contain some payload
     Xrm.Page.getAttributes("xxx").setValue(e.data);
  });
}
```

Now in your child window only send the result using postMessage

```
window.opener.postMessage("I'm the result", '*');
```

I usually handle the scenarios that you described this way. The other solution would be to create a callback on parent window

```
window.callback = function() {
   //do your stuff here
}
```

and from child window calling  this callback:

```
childWindow.opener.callback();
```

But personally I prefer the postMessage approach, I had some problems with the callbacks sometimes.